# What does '%BZ' mean in materials science?

Tags: material-science, notation, crystals, graphene, chemical-compounds

[image]

Also, for that matter, what does k_II mean?

Comment: Brillouin Zone?

Comment: I just had a thought... Does BZ stand for Brillouin Zone?     But still... What is %BZ?  And k_II?

Comment: Intercalation between epitaxial silicon carbide and graphene? You'll need to tell us where the diagram came from forus to help.

Comment: As a general rule, providing a figure like that without a full citation to the paper where it appears cuts out valuable context which makes answering harder. And it also hurts the authors of the paper by reducing its altmetric score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The abbreviation BZ stands for Brillouin Zone, almost universally.
- The material depicted is not a uniform solid, and it has at least two components each with different sizes of unit cell and thus different sizes of Brillouin zone. The SiC subscript denotes that the axis is in units of the BZ for the bulk silicon carbide component.
- The percentage sign means simply that $k$ is measured in percentage of the size of the SiC BZ.
- The $||$ subscript indicates the parallel component of the vector $\vec k$. This presumably means the component parallel to the surface, but that could change depending on the details of the context provided by the text surrounding the figure.